# How can I set the default font size in Google Reader?

Tags: google-reader, font

I know that I can increase the font size for the current item by pressing `=`, but how can I set the default size?  I'm tired of having to hit `=` twice every time I come back to Google Reader, especially since I primarily use the mouse with it, and it's annoying to switch to the keyboard just to up the font size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of any setting built into Google Reader. However, there are many styles already built (and you can build your own) and use the Stylish plugin for [FF](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2108/) or [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe). You can download some styles at [userstyles.org](http://userstyles.org/) With a minimal amount of CSS knowledge, you can modify the text to your liking.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who's interested, here's the stylesheet I wound up creating for [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2108/):

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);

@-moz-document url-prefix("http://www.google.com/reader/") {
  .entry-body { font-size: 125% }
}
```

This makes all the entries larger, not just the current one.